# how to display a pop up message with ok and cancel button in windows phone 7 application development

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am building an app for windows phone 7. I want to display a messagebox with both OK and Cancel button. Moreover the message box should come in the center of the application. Is it possible to have a design in my messagebox other than the message box shown by defaut?

My code is:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Net;
 using System.Windows;
 using System.Windows.Controls;
 using System.Windows.Documents;
 using System.Windows.Input;
 using System.Windows.Media;
 using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
 using System.Windows.Shapes;
 using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

 namespace KejriwalPhoneApp
{
public partial class Donate : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public Donate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    var customMessageBox = new CustomMessageBox()
    {
        LeftButtonContent = "Ok",
        RightButtonContent = "Cancel",
        Content = new TextBlock()
        {   // All TextBlock (or other control) properties are work here
            Text = "This Will Take You Out Of The App And Forward You To Our Contribution Website!",
            TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap
        }
    };

    customMessageBox.Dismissed += (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (args.Result == CustomMessageBoxResult.LeftButton)
        {
            // Action when "ok" pressed
            donation.Source = new Uri("http://mobiledonation.vzons.com/ArvindKejriwal", UriKind.Absolute);

            donation.Loaded += (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
            {
                donation.Navigate(new Uri("http://mobiledonation.vzons.com/ArvindKejriwal", UriKind.Absolute));
            };
        }
        else if (args.Result == CustomMessageBoxResult.RightButton)
        {
            // Action when "cancal" pressed, optional
        }
        else
        {
            // Action when back key pressed, optional
        }
    };

    customMessageBox.Show();
}

    }
}
```

}

This is my complete code now for displaying a pop up message. I am getting the following error:

```
1. The type or namespace name 'CustomMessageBox' couldnot be found
2. The name CustomMessageBoxResult doesnot exist in the current context
3. A local variable named 'sender' cannot be declared in this scope because it would    give a different meaning to 'sender', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else
4. A local variable named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a     different meaning to 'e', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to   denote something else
5. The name 'CustomMessageBoxResult' does not exist in the current context
```

Please help me to fix these

Comment: You COULD build a new control that mimics the message box functionality but honestly it is much easier to download rad controls by telerik. They are worth their weight in gold. I use them in all my apps now.

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/

Comment: donate to AAP...I hope you publish this app very soon.. good idea

Comment: @Sarvesh its already published for iphone and android. I have started for windows and this is my first app for windows phone. As i am new to this domain its taking time to complete but hope it will be done by this week

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use any other library Message box just use windows Default Message with some editing

```
MessageBoxResult m = MessageBox.Show("Heading", "What do want to say to user so that he/she can press ok or cancel", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
if (m == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
{
   //do what you want when user press cancel
}
else if (m == MessageBoxResult.OK)
{
   //Do what you want when user press ok
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use CustomMessageBox from the [WP toolkit](https://phone.codeplex.com).
So add toolkit, include `Microsoft.Phone.Controls` into your .cs file. CMB can't be shown while the page is not completely loaded, so your code should look like this:

```
    public Donate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        var customMessageBox = new CustomMessageBox()
        {
            LeftButtonContent = "Ok",
            RightButtonContent = "Cancel",
            Content = new TextBlock()
            {   // All TextBlock (or other control) properties are work here
                Text = "This Will Take You Out Of The App And Forward You To Our Contribution Website!",
                TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap
            }
        };

        customMessageBox.Dismissed += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (args.Result == CustomMessageBoxResult.LeftButton)
            {
                // Action when "ok" pressed
                donation.Source = new Uri("http://mobiledonation.vzons.com/ArvindKejriwal", UriKind.Absolute);

                donation.Loaded += (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) =>
                {
                    donation.Navigate(new Uri("http://mobiledonation.vzons.com/ArvindKejriwal", UriKind.Absolute));
                };
            }
            else if (args.Result == CustomMessageBoxResult.RightButton)
            {
                // Action when "cancal" pressed, optional
            }
            else
            {
                // Action when back key pressed, optional
            }
        };

        customMessageBox.Show();
    }
```

CMB doesn't stop a program flow, so what you want to process only after you get result of the CMB, should be added to CMB Dismissed event.

Comment: @user3156298 Did you include wp toolkit library to your project references? Here is the insctuctions how to do it http://phone.codeplex.com/releases/view/107923

Answer (score 0):

Other possible way is to use Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerService MessageBox(no 3rd party toolkit needed)

add a reference to Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerService library and also add a using directive on the top of the page where the message is to be shown up

Just follow the code below

```
 List<string> messageboxitm = new List<string>();
 messageboxitm.Add("Okay");
 messageboxitm.Add("Cancel");
 string title = "Confirm Buy";
 string displaymessg = "You must buy the app to go further, do you want to buy the app?"; 
 IAsyncResult result1 = Guide.BeginShowMessageBox(title, displaymessg, messageboxitm, 0, MessageBoxIcon.Alert, new AsyncCallback(OnBuyMessageclosed), null);

private void OnBuyMessageclosed(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            int? buttonIndex = Guide.EndShowMessageBox(ar);
            switch (buttonIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => ConfirmBuy("Okay"));
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => ConfirmBuy("Cancel"));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }


  public void ConfirmBuy(string title)
    {
        if (title == "Okay")
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
               //Action
            });
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.